# wpf datagrid from textfile add row vb

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, row

Greetings! I am very new to WPF. I have a simple need i guess. I need to display eachline of textfile in datagrid. number of lines in file are not know before.

i am using streamreader to reader the line from text file.

when i am trying to add the content to new row, a new row is getting added but with no content.

`grid1.items.add(t)` 'where t is the line read from the text file

i think t to be items, i do know how to add items and add content to it. Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advance.

- sri

Answer (score 0):

```
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("filename.txt");
        string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (string c in columnnames)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(c);
        }
        string newline;
        while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string[] values = newline.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = values[i];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        file.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Try this

Comment: I thank you for the prompt response. I am working on WPF and this way it is not solving. i am writing as below Sub test()
        Dim t As String
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("D:\1TXC15_TRACE.txt")
        While reader.Peek <> -1
            t = reader.ReadLine()

            Grid1.Items.Add(New Binding("Hi" & t.ToString()))

        End While
        reader.Close()
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Adding columns and setting proper Binding is must.

Everything in code :

```
string[] lines = {"line1", "line2" };

DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
Dgrd.Columns.Add(col1);
col1.Binding = new Binding(".");

Dgrd.Items.Add(lines[0]);
```

Adding column in XAML :

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding .}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Without directly Items.Add :

```
string[] lines = { "line1", "line2" };
Dgrd.ItemsSource = lines.ToList();

<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding .}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```